# SetDelegate causes 'unrecognized selector' exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, unrecognized-selector

I have a UICollectionView, which Cells hold a Product each.
As I am loading in the Images on demand, to keep the upfront bandwidth low i want to update the UICollectionViewCell after the Download has finished with the Product Image, instead of the placeholder.

So I have the following:

#### Product.h

```
@class Product;
@protocol CWProductDelegate
-(void)CWProductDidFinishLoadingImages:(Product *)product;
@end

@interface Product : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * bottleImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * bottleImage2x;
@property (nonatomic, strong, getter = chooseBottleImage) NSData * stdBottleImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isAvailable;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * labelImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * labelImage2x;
@property (nonatomic, strong, getter = chooseLabelImage) NSData * stdLabelImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * origin;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * pourImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * pourImage2x;
@property (nonatomic, strong, getter = choosePourImage) NSData * stdPourImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * price;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * productCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * productDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * scent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * setting;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * vintage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * wineType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * varietal;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *lineitem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *merchantViews;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CWProductDelegate> delegate;
@end

@interface Product (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

+ (void)manage:(Product *)product merchantViews:(NSArray *)merchantViews;
+ (NSArray *)redWines;
+ (NSArray *)whiteWines;
+ (NSArray *)whiteRecommendations;
+ (NSArray *)redRecommendations;


- (void)addMerchantViewsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)removeMerchantViewsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)addMerchantViews:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeMerchantViews:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)getProductImages;
- (void)fetchRetinaImages;

@end
```

#### CWProductCell.h

```
@interface CWProductCell : UICollectionViewCell <CWProductDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *productName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Product *product;


-(void)setLabelText:(NSString *)text;
-(void)addImagesToScrollView;

@end
```

#### (CollectionView Stuff)

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  CWProductCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ProductCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


if (indexPath.row < _redRecommendations)
{
  Product *product = _redWineArray[indexPath.row];
  [product setDelegate:cell];
  ####### THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION IS RISED#####
  cell.product = product;
  cell.productName.text = cell.product.name;

  [cell addImagesToScrollView];

} else {
  Product *product = _whiteWineArray[indexPath.row - _redRecommendations];
  cell.product = product;
  cell.productName.text = cell.product.name;
  [cell addImagesToScrollView];
}
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapCell = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapCell:)];
  [cell.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapCell];


  return cell;
}
```

I'm getting following error:

> -[Product setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x995f350

Comment: What's the `Product` class?  I believe `unrecognized selector` means that the object you're sending the message to doesn't have a method by that name.  (Your `Product` class has no method `setDelegate:`).

Comment: Post your Product class. Are you sure it has a 'delegate' property?

Comment: Updated to the full class, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding:

> @synthesize delegate;

to the `Product.m`

Answer (score 0):

Is the object from the `_redWineArray[indexPath.row];` Definatly an instace of Product?

//Not correct
Use `@property(nonatomic, weak) id<CWProductDelegate> delegate;`

Comment: (Did that, same result). There should be no difference in setting it via the shorthand, right?

Comment: Nah I don't think so. Just making sure.

Comment: @BenAvery You do not need `nonatomic` to have a setter and getter generated. Atomic properties get synthesized setters and getters too.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, No idea where I came up with that one of those weird things I assumed along the way.

Comment: Even though using nonatomic, it doesnt really change the outcome :)

Comment: And yes, product is not nil and its an instance of Product.

Comment: Can I move answer to a comment?

Comment: It looks like your Product property does declare a delegate property, and with a recent llvm compiler, that should synthesize the getter and setter methods. Post the code that populates your _redWine array with Product objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is your `Product.h`, which defines the `public properties` and `methods` of the `Product` class.

```
@class Product;
@protocol CWProductDelegate
-(void)CWProductDidFinishLoadingImages:(Product *)product;
@end
```

This does not include a `setDelegate:` method.  If you included this method in y

Comment: Updated the Product.H, sorry about that.